# Is there XY Graph block in Xcos

Tags: matlab, simulink, scilab, xcos

In *Simulink*, there is an `XY Graph` block. Is there a similar block in *Xcos*?

I work in Xcos. When I use `CScope` in my model, I get a graph showing either s-t (coordinate-time) or v-t (speed-time) dependency. But I need my s and v to be the axes of the graph (I need to show how speed depends on the coordinate). In Simulink, I should use the `XY Graph` block. How can I do it in Xcos?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSCOPXY block (in the Sinks Palette).